# Conditional Compilation is Turned Off VS 2012 razor javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, razor, visual-studio-2012

I have searched SO and not found a solution to this problem. I have code like this:

```
<script>
$("AddToFavorites").Click(function() {
    var apiLink = "/url/AddToFavorites?id=" + @Model.RecipeId;
    $.ajax({
        url: apiLink,
        type: "GET"
    });
});
</script>
```

the . in Model.RecipeId gets underlined and I get a compiler error of:

```
Conditional compilation is turned off
```

Is it not possible to use c# code in a javscript block? If this is the case, how do I get around it to make the url dynamic in a case like this?

Thanks.

Comment: Put `Model.RecipeId` between single quotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the code to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("AddToFavorites").click(function() {
    var apiLink = "/url/AddToFavorites?id=" + "@(Model.MerchantID)";
    $.ajax({
        url: apiLink,
        type: "GET"
    });
});
</script>
```

also you may want to add

```
/*@cc_on @*/
```

if the error continues to happen.